# Palindrome with multiple checks

Tags: javascript

I need to create a palindrome that accepts a string and boolean to validate several conditions.

Now if a sentence has the letters mirrored but has different spaces will result false, same characters without whitespace present will result false.

My problem is the next test which *needs to ignore the whitespace and if the characters are indeed palindromic will return **true*** in my test return false.

This is what I got so far (they are other conditions to be passed as well)

```
function palindrome(str) {
  let reChar = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\w\s/g, '');
  let checkPalindrome = reChar.split('').reverse().join('');
  if (str === '') {
    return false;
  }
  return (reChar === checkPalindrome);
}
```

Thanks for any help

Note: I think I have to pass a 2nd parameter but I don't have an idea how.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Share the sample input and expected output.

Comment: when checks same sentence as previous test will ignore the whitespace... and if its characters *are* indeed palindromic needs to return true. My result is false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT*: it seems that you want your function to support both ignoring and not ignoring whitespace. If that's the case you can pass a flag to determine this.

```
// only use when ignoring whitespace
.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Furthermore, your special case check that makes `''` not be a palindrome can be moved to the top since we can return `false` immediately if this is the case and there's no need to do anything:

Example:

```js
function palindrome(str, ignoreWS) {
  if (str === '') {
    return false;
  }
  
  let reChar = ignoreWS
    ? str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '')
    : str.toLowerCase();

  let checkPalindrome = reChar.split('').reverse().join('');
  return (reChar === checkPalindrome);
}

console.log(
  palindrome('a b c     cb a', true) // true
)

console.log(
  palindrome('a b c     cb a') // false
)

console.log(
  palindrome('abccba') // true
)

console.log(
  palindrome('') // false
)
```

Comment: if I do this (which I did before) fails for "If a sentence has the letters mirrored but has different spaces, then it's not a pure palindrome" expected false but returns true.

Comment: Well you cannot both ignore and not ignore whitespace...you might want 2 functions then or pass a parameter that determines whether to ignore or not

Comment: that will make sense but all test needs to be in one function...but probably if I have a second parameter as  boolean. The problem is I don't know how...

Comment: @GeorgeWatkis glad to help mate :)